# Should a concrete pool look like this after an acid wash?

Tags: concrete, pool

I'd like to redo after the contractor who did an acid wash of my pool:

[image]

But before I start, I'd like to understand (since I have never seen the pool acid washed before): is that what "the product" of an acid wash should look like?